# NodeJs vs SpringBoot REST Controller and Multithreading

Tags: java, node.js, spring, multithreading, rest

Lets say I want to build a REST controller with a few endpoints for an online store. For example, it will have

- a GET endpoint to view order details
- a POST to create an order
- and a PUT to update an order

With Spring and Java, the Spring framework's @RestController will of course create a new thread automatically for each request. There is no work required to manually create a new thread for each request.

On using NodeJS for the same work,
I've heard (and googled) alot about NodeJS and multithreading -

- NodeJS cannot multithread https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-node-js-is-a-single-threaded-language/
- NodeJS cannot do 'true' multithreading https://snyk.io/blog/node-js-multithreading-worker-threads-pros-cons/

My question is, can a NodeJS controller multithread in the same way a Spring RestController can? Meaning ...

- It will spawn each request in a new thread automatically
- No manual coding/creation of these threads is necessary (it is entirely handled by the framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Idea about Java is partially correct.

> @RestController will of course create a new thread automatically for
> each request

When we come to your real question, Yes nodeJS applications come as a single-threaded.  NodeJS is built with the concept of event-driven architecture and it has its own infinity event loop to maintain the concurrency and handle the request and response with the non-blocking I/O NodeJS can perform asynchronous operations also because of the event loop.

### Let's go into deep

When we go into node js deep the node js application is working under the 2 basics concepts of

1. Asynchronous
2. Non-blocking I/O

Non-blocking i/o  means working with multiple requests without blocking the thread for a single request. Thats mean Nodejs not used for cpu intensive works.

Asynchronous is executing a callback function. Callback function is a kind of function which executed in eventloop and allows to run other code in meantime. The node js is not waiting for completion of the these functions. NodeJS is called these functions when they are completed as soon as possible.

### How tasks are delegated?

When the node js application starts to execute the script first, the tasks are pushed to the call stack and the script which may make async API calls, schedules timers are push to the event loop.

### How tasks are executed?

When the NodeJS app starts it starts the event loop and initializes it. Before going to execute callbacks it checks the call stack for more tasks to execute. If their is any tasks which has done their job in the event queue the call back is send from the event queue to call stack and executed.

To perform async overations the node js use special library called libua and it is manage a thread pool. That is composed of four threads used to delegate operations that are too heavy for the event loop. thats how behind the seen multithreading come  to the execute parallely.

---

But if you want multithreading for heavy Cpu offensive tasks, Just look at the [worker thred.](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

If you want to scale your project just look at the [node js clusters](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

[Don't Block the Event Loop (or the Worker Pool)](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop)

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS can facilitate one thread per request, however -

- These aren't true threads in the sense of JVM threads. A given 'thread' in NodeJS can't know the state of another in the pool (at least not in the same way a Java thread could eg/ wait(..) notify(..) etc.) So if you are a purist, you can't strictly call these threads.
- Where Java threads all run within the same JVM. Each NodeJS 'thread' runs inside a seperare Node runtime environment.
- NodeJS doesn't provide a way for the creation/management of these threads to be done automatically like the Spring framework. Some coding is required required to set this up, see the link.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-many-parallel-http-requests-using-node-js/amp/